# SQL Lite retrieve Proper Record

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a table named ChatThreadMember. I am attaching the data of the table so that my problem will be conveyed properly.

[image]

I am trying to fetch such a ChatThreadId which contains all the ReceiverInteral that I'll pass.

For ex. when I pass the following 3 ReceiverInternals

1. 'F7269470-B8C9-447C-8E85-555D9ECF82B6'
2. '79D49515-A34C-47A7-BDE8-667778B0327C'
3. '9E682E2B-FB3C-41F3-9192-ABFD97D5A8F5'

I should get only `6CE1F6A9-8254-4D5A-8C9D-FEC680B60B2F` as the ChatThreadId as it is the only ChatThreadId  which contains all the 3 ReceiverInternals.
However with my all trials I am getting `DF04A5D4-E586-4398-B8DB-13B411EOED5D` also along with `6CE1F6A9-8254-4D5A-8C9D-FEC680B60B2F` which I don't need.

My query is:

```
SELECT  cth.ChatThreadId from ChatThreadMember cth where cth.ReceiverInternal in
('F7269470-B8C9-447C-8E85-555D9ECF82B6','79D49515-A34C-47A7-BDE8-667778B0327C','9E682E2B-FB3C-41F3-9192-ABFD97D5A8F5')
and
cth.ChatThreadId not in(
SELECT cth.ChatThreadId from ChatThreadMember cth where cth.ReceiverInternal in
(Select cth.ReceiverInternal from ChatThreadMember cth where cth.ReceiverInternal not in ('F7269470-B8C9-447C-8E85-555D9ECF82B6','79D49515-A34C-47A7-BDE8-667778B0327C','9E682E2B-FB3C-41F3-9192-ABFD97D5A8F5')
))
group by cth.ChatThreadId
```

I am stuck with the problem. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want all IDs for which all ReceiverInternal required exist. So select them, count them in the HAVING clause and dismiss IDs with a lower count.

```
select chatthreadid 
from chatthreadmember
where receiverinternal in
(
  'F7269470-B8C9-447C-8E85-555D9ECF82B6',
  '79D49515-A34C-47A7-BDE8-667778B0327C',
  '9E682E2B-FB3C-41F3-9192-ABFD97D5A8F5'
)
group by chatthreadid
having count(distinct receiverinternal) = 3;
```